# How to set hidden field value in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I want to set hidden field value in my form UI component. Also, I want to pass that value from the data provider and set it in form UI component as that value would be dynamic.

I have set hidden field with data scope.

Now the question is I'm getting the value in data provider and passing it to form component but while submitting the form I'm getting nothing in request.

Please help for the same. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please put below code to your UI file.

```
<form>
    ...
    <fieldset>
        ...
        <hidden name="hidden_example">
            <settings>
                <value>hidden value</value>
            </settings>
        </hidden>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Hope it works!

and if you want to pass value please follow.
[How can we set store value in UI form Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/251150/how-can-we-set-store-value-in-ui-form-magento-2)